# Get file name and Data Type from ELCAlbumPickerController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am working on ELCAlbumPickerController, i am able to select multiple  images and upload, but in addition i want to get the file name and datatype of the file. how can i do that?

I am able to select either image or video , how can i select both image and video and any file at a time?

Please find my code below for your reference.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"elc-ios-icon.png"];
    NSArray *Items   = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        @"A text line",
                        anImage, nil];

    UIActivityViewController *ActivityView =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
     initWithActivityItems:Items applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:ActivityView animated:YES completion:nil];

}
- (IBAction)launchController
{


    ELCAlbumPickerController *albumController = [[ELCAlbumPickerController alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
    ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:albumController];
    [albumController setParent:elcPicker];
    [elcPicker setDelegate:self];

    ELCImagePickerDemoAppDelegate *app = (ELCImagePickerDemoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([app.viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]){
        [app.viewController presentViewController:elcPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        [app.viewController presentModalViewController:elcPicker animated:YES];
    }
    [elcPicker release];
    [albumController release];
}

- (IBAction)launchSpecialController
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    self.specialLibrary = library;
    [library release];
    NSMutableArray *groups = [NSMutableArray array];
    [_specialLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if (group) {
            [groups addObject:group];
        } else {
            // this is the end
            [self displayPickerForGroup:[groups objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        self.chosenImages = nil;
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Album Error: %@ - %@", [error localizedDescription], [error localizedRecoverySuggestion]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        NSLog(@"A problem occured %@", [error description]);
        // an error here means that the asset groups were inaccessable.`
        // Maybe the user or system preferences refused access.
    }];
}

- (void)displayPickerForGroup:(ALAssetsGroup *)group
{
    ELCAssetTablePicker *tablePicker = [[ELCAssetTablePicker alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
    tablePicker.singleSelection = YES;
    tablePicker.immediateReturn = YES;

    ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tablePicker];
    elcPicker.delegate = self;
    tablePicker.parent = elcPicker;

    // Move me
    tablePicker.assetGroup = group;
    [tablePicker.assetGroup setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allAssets]];

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]){
        [self presentViewController:elcPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        [self presentModalViewController:elcPicker animated:YES];
    }
    [tablePicker release];
    [elcPicker release];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
    }
}

#pragma mark ELCImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods

- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)]){
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    for (UIView *v in [_scrollView subviews]) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }

    CGRect workingFrame = _scrollView.frame;
    workingFrame.origin.x = 0;

    images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[info count]];


    for(NSDictionary *dict in info) {

        UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [images addObject:image];

        UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        imageview.frame = workingFrame;

        [_scrollView addSubview:imageview];
        [imageview release];

        workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;
    }

    self.chosenImages = images;
    NSLog(@"Images:%@",images);
    [_scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(workingFrame.origin.x, workingFrame.size.height)];

    for (int i=0; i< images.count; i++) {
        NSData *image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(images[i], 0.1);
        NSLog(@"NSDATA:%@",image);

        NSMutableString *urlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"name=thefile&&filename=recording"];
        [urlString appendFormat:@"%@", image];
        NSLog(@"urlstring:%@",urlString);
        NSData *postData = [urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                   allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
        NSString * namecount=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fn%i.png",i];
    NSString * baseurl =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://199.198.12.555/serviceService.svc/serviceupload?fileName=%@",namecount];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:baseurl];
        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
        [urlRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:image];

        NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
        [connection start];

    }
    NSLog(@"%@",images[0]);
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)images.count);

}
-(IBAction)upload:(id)sender{


}


- (void)elcImagePickerControllerDidCancel:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)]){
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [_specialLibrary release];
    [_scrollView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
@implementation APActivityProvider
- (id) activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
          itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
    if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter] )
        return @"This is a #twitter post!";
    if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook] )
        return @"This is a facebook post!";
    if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage] )
        return @"SMS message text";
    if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail] )
        return @"Email text here!";
    if ( [activityType isEqualToString:@"it.albertopasca.myApp"] )
        return @"OpenMyapp custom text";
    return nil;
}
- (id) activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController { return @""; }
@end


@implementation APActivityIcon
- (NSString *)activityType { return @"it.albertopasca.myApp"; }
- (NSString *)activityTitle { return @"Open Maps"; }
- (UIImage *) activityImage { return [UIImage imageNamed:@"elc-ios-icon.png"]; }
- (BOOL) canPerformWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems { return YES; }
- (void) prepareWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems { }
- (UIViewController *) activityViewController { return nil; }
- (void) performActivity {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"maps://"]];
}
@end
```

Thanks

Comment: +1 for using APActivityProvider!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the asset URL using the key `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` which would give the 'name', but that probably won't be very useful as its probably a UUID. The `UIImagePickerControllerMediaType` key contains the type.